# lua index doesn't return multiple values

Tags: indexing, lua

Object should contain a pair of values for each index.

```
object = {}

function object:new()
  self.elements = {}
  setmetatable(self, self)
  return self
end

function object:append(first, second)
  self.elements[#self.elements + 1] = {first, second}
end

function object:__index(k)
  return unpack(self.elements[k])
end
```

When I try to access values by index I get only first value of that pair.

```
o:append(1,2)
o:append(3,4)

> return o[1]
1
```

Direct __index method involving produce expected result.

```
> return o:__index(1)
1       2
```

What is the reason?

Comment: That's the way it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be no reason, but keeping the semantics of table indexing without metatables.

The behaviour is documented in the [Reference Manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#2.4). The code explaining the semantics of the index metamethod adjusts the values returned to one when `__index` is a function.

Comment: It's very sadly. Multiple return from __index metamethod doesn't break backward compatibility with previous written code.

Comment: Well, `{ t[ i ] }` should have length `1`. This does not hold anymore when your indexing operation returns multiple values.